# Updating AngularJS Model of table inserts new cell and removes another

Tags: angularjs

I had an interesting problem today with AngularJS which I thought I would post:

In my application I have a model from which I create an HTML table using ng-repeat, additionally I have an input field which is tied to another model and I have registered a watch function to that model. When I enter some text into the input field, the function writes that text into the currently selected cell of the table.

Once the function completed something wired happened. Instead of updating the value of the selected cell, a new one was inserted at the current position and the cells were shifted to the right and the last cell was removed from the row. Obviously I would have expected that the cells stayed that their current position and only the child elements were updated.

Here is a short example of my code. The model:

```
//The model is initialized with empty strings, later the input is supplied by the user
$scope.master.rows = [["", "", ""], ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]];
```

The HTML snippet:

```
<table ng-model="master.rows">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in master.rows">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row"
            ng-click="master.click($event.target)">{{ col }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the click function is executed, the current cell is set in the scope such that the watch function can retrieve the x and y index from it and use it to update the model:

```
$scope.$watch("master.attributes", function (value) {
    var x = $scope.master.current[0].cellIndex;
    var y = $scope.master.current[0].parentNode.rowIndex;
    $scope.master.rows[y][x] = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this behavior because I was writing directly to the model object. So I changed the model a little to contain objects and I wrote the value to an object member instead. The new model looked like this:

```
$scope.master.rows = [[{value: ""}, {value: ""}, {value: ""}],
                      [{value: ""}, {value: ""}, {value: ""}],
                      [{value: ""}, {value: ""}, {value: ""}]
                     ];
```

In the HTML snippet I changed the expression to:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in row" ng-click="master.click($event.target)">{{ col.value }}</td>
```

In the watch function:

```
$scope.master.rows[y][x].value = value;
```